# The Biggest Data Management problems

Tags: synchronization, reporting, rdbms, database

Where does current technology fall short of industry demands in the context of data and information management?

In other words, where should the software engineering industry as a whole be focusing its efforts in these areas?

Comment: should be a community wiki. This has no right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong and transparent support for [temporal databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database)

Storage space is cheap and CPUs are fast nowadays - therefore, you should be always be able to see your data as it was at any point in the past (with transaction level granularity). That functionality should be transparent from the developer's standpoint.   There are a number of solutions out there, but I find that they all have limitations of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Physical data independence and richer type support

Better support for business rules in the database

SQL is still the dominant database technology in the commercial world. SQL is not relational however and SQL DBMSs are not actually RDBMSs. In my view a true industrial-strength RDBMS implementation would be a big leap forward for the industry.